# Orthogonality of Hankel functions, what are the relations?

Tags: special-functions, orthogonality, bessel-functions

What are the relations for orthogonality of Hankel's relations defined via:

$H^{(1)}_{m}(z) \equiv J_{n}(z) + i Y_{n}(z)$

$H^{(2)}_{m}(z) \equiv J_{n}(z) - i Y_{n}(z)$

I have looked at some books but could not find the orthogonality relations(except for second kind of Bessels functions), I will appreciate any help.